# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Ellipse to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I defined a class a very simple class called Ellipse:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Ellipse extends MovieClip {

    public function Ellipse() {
        trace("HI")
    }

   }
}
```

Then I tried to add it into the main timeline using:

```
var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse()
addChild(ellipse);
```

But it keeps on saying that

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 10 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of      type Ellipse to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you use Flex's built-in [Ellipse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Ellipse.html) class when creating the instance? 
Because there is no other way, or you are missing something in the other part(s) of your code.